# Body field in colorbox

Tags: 7, javascript

Is it possible to have body trimmed to lets say 150 chars with read more link, and when you click read more, full body field opens in colorbox ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) installed, you can install [Colorbox Node](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) & Overlay which will let you create a colorbox node link with a `colorbox-node` class (e.g. `<a class="colorbox-node" href="/my/node/path">My Node</a>`).

In your theme's node preprocess function, you can add that class to the read more link:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node() in your theme's template.php
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'teaser') {
    $variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['attributes']['class'] = 'colorbox-node';
  }
}
```

You'll need to adjust your theme's stylesheet rules to hide the non-body fields (and other styling as necessary), but it will work.

Comment: Thx Shawn, but its a bit to much for me.

Comment: I'm doubtful there's a turnkey solution for you. This solution requires 3 things: knowing how download/install 2 modules (one of which is built into D7 core), knowing how to modify your customize your theme's preprocess_node function in template.php (or creating a subtheme for that purpose), and alter your theme's stylesheet rules (i.e. editing style.css). Learn how to do those 3 tasks (they're fairly common) and revisit the solution later.

Comment: Would this work for all nodes created for particular content type automaticly after i do those modifications ?

Comment: This will work for any node displayed in teaser mode that has a read-more link at the end of it.